# Is there a Way to Navigate a Frame Without Ever Displaying Navigation Buttons?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm using a XAML frame in a .NET 4 WPF desktop application to display information about different modes of operation. I don't want the user to be able to navigate freely, the code controls what is displayed in the frame. I've been able to achieve this restriction by removing the last back entry each time the frame navigates:

```
    void FunctionalFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        FunctionalFrame.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
```

Even though this works, it has a problem visually, because after the first navigation the forward and back buttons and the navigation bar appear in a disabled state. It would be nice if the user never saw the navigation controls at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried setting [`NavigationUIVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.navigationuivisibility) to `Hidden`?

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

On the frame you need to set NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"

```
<Frame Source="PageSearch.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
```